# Contents ofAzure worker role e:\approot folder disappearing on instance reboot

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

When a Windows Azure worker role instance is rebooted from within the Azure portal, are the contents of the e:\approot folder deleted?
I have an elevated startup task which checks for the existence of a file in this folder before adding some registry settings.  This has worked in the past but is now failing because the file it expects to find is no longer there following a portal-induced reboot.
If I perform a 'shutdown' command from within the startup task, the instance reboots but the contents of e:\approot are unaffected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is that when the Reboot button is clicked on the Azure portal, the contents of the AppRoot folder are deleted and the package redeployed.

To test, deploy something (anything...) to an Azure instance.  RDP onto the instance and create a file (test.txt) in the AppRoot folder (this will be on the E: or F: drive).

Click the Reboot button on the portal.  Wait for restart, then RDP onto the instance again - test.txt no longer exists.

Note that if you RDP onto the instance and choose Restart from the Windows UI, then test.txt is not deleted.

Comment: Do not count on this behavior.  This is an implementation detail that might change.  Reimage has a well-known behavior, but reboot might or might not do as you say in the future.  The only guarantee that you have for reboot is that you instance will be rebooted.  Right now, it says nothing about the state of the drive (in fact, I would say that what you observe sounds like a regression that was supposed to be fixed).

Answer (score 5):

As others have already said, the contents of the drive are not lost on reboot.  What has most likely happened is that you are hardcoding "e:\approot" in your startup task.  You should not do this.  I would hazard a guess that when you reboot, the drive has moved to f:\ or some other drive.  I have seen this quite a bit.

Instead, you should reference %ROLEROOT% environment variable.  That will point to the correct drive and path (e.g. "%ROLEROOT%\AppRoot") on reboot regardless of where the drive actually gets moved to.

Comment: I'm not hardcoding any paths.  The startup batch file writes the time to a text file so I know the instance has been started at least once.  This file is created by default in Azure in e:\(or f:\)approot.

I've tested this further.  If I RDP to a started instance, create a file e:\approot\ken.txt, then come out to the Azure portal and click the Reboot Instance button, when the instance comes up again, the ken.txt file no longer exists.  This implies the reboot process is recreating the approot folder and redeploying my package.

Comment: @kenxl - I misunderstood your issue then.  I thought you were saying that you were trying to launch something you copied to disk locally.  You should not count on files copied outside of your resources drive (using LocalResources) to be there.  As you have observed, the app drive can be moved or recreated on demand.  Your resource drive is more likely to stick around (assuming you use sticky storage).  Regardless of the file existing/not existing, you would do well to make your startup task idempotent and handle any errors if the file is missing but settings were already applied.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the conent of e:\approot will "disappear". The original content I mean.

This is the location where your role code is located, so it is not being deleted in any way, otherwise your role will not work at all. It might be reinitiated on every reboot, however I really doubt that is true.

If you use startup task to check for something you manually add, I suggest that you use a [Local Storage Resource](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-local-storage-resources/). Keep anything that is not part of your original package deployment in a Local Resource. You have the option to keep the content of this folder(s) (or clean it) upon role "recycle".

If your startup task is checking for some contents of your role code/package to be there, I suggest that you implement some wait logic in the cmd/batch file you are using. And also mark the startup task as "background" type, so it does not block the instance startup. As I said, e:\approot cannot be empty, because this is where your code resides! The content might come there later, but for sure it will not stay empty.

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/RobBlackwell/AzureRunMe to deploy a java app.  The AzureRunMe C# package gets deployed to AppRoot, but my java app is being installed on the C: drive.  My fallback is to create my file using local storage (as you suggest) or on the C: drive, but I'd like to understand what's happening to AppRoot.

Comment: I just took a quick look at the AzureRunMe project. I see a serious missing from it. You can concat the author and suggest providing additional configuration keyword expansions, or environment variables with values to Local Storage. I strongly suggest that all and any additional data, being copied/depolyed additionally to the Azure package should reside in a Local Storage. Not approot, not just in C: (although the Local Storage resources are by default allocated in C drive).

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Take your point about using LocalStorage - I can easily change this.  It's worth noting that the Azure portal reboot feature is actually a 'Reboot and Redeploy' feature though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't count on local changes surviving (or not surviving) updates or restarts - changes may persist or may be lost.

Your code should be designed to account for that, period. You can store temporary data locally to resume faster, but that data persisting is not guaranteed, so you should have that data in some durable storage like SQL Azure or Azure Storage.

The behavior you see might be caused by installing software updates. I'm not sure that's how it works, but imagine Azure infrastructure decides to roll on Windows updates on some of your instances VMs. Installing updates can take long, so Azure will just stop your instance, then start another (already updated) clean VM and deploy and start your role instance there. If that happens all local changes will of course be lost - your instance will be started on a fresh clean VM and your current VM will be discarded. That's just a speculation, but I imagine it's quite realistic.