# Azure: Worker Role write on c:\ or local storage

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I am in doubts.

I have a code which create a file "foo.txt" and then copy it to a blob with UploadFile().
If I undesrtand well azure concept I can't create this file in "c:\" ?
I am obliged to use local storage in my ServiceDefinition.csdef, and create it in azureLocalResource.RootPath.

But there is a c:\ drive for write (a d:\ for the OS and a e:\ for code), isn't it?
What is it use ?
Can we just use it in the start-up task ?

I ask because I believe that code ran with c:\ util this day.
And I can't find why a similar code don't work in a new worker role.
(It is a file and directory issue, not just file)

**[Answer]**
I can create this file in c: but it is highly recommended to use local storage API, because the drive letter isn't always the same (after a reboot for example).
Local storage is just a short cut for use the read&write drive of the current instance.
In specific case of startup task, we can acces to this storage by 2 ways : with the azure API in a c# program/script (see [this topic](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/using-a-local-storage-resource-from-a-startup-task)) or with environment variables (see [this topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974419.aspx)).

Comment: There's no need to add the answer to your question. You've already marked @Sandrino's answer, which people can easily find and upvote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't want to tie yourself to fixed driveletters. It's true that C:\ is most of the time the data disk, D:\ is most of the time the OS and E:\ is most of the time where your code resides.

But you can't count on this, that's why I say most of the time. Like Ryan explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8262363/384546), it could be possible that your application disk changes from E:\ to F:\ after a reboot, well the same thing **could** apply for your data disk. Only the **LocalResource** can tell you where you can save your files, so I suggest you use it.

If you have startup tasks that need to work with files, you should also work with LocalResources. This is possible by using PowerShell: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/using-a-local-storage-resource-from-a-startup-task

Comment: Ok, I read a book which said that the name are defined ... Thank for you answer, I was convinced of local storage and c:\ are totally different, but no.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you use LocalStorage, its intended for this purpose and by using the api you can retrieve the path/drive instead of having a hard-coded dependency on a specific drive location. This also helps avoid any permissions issues as the LocalStorage will be at the beck and call of the process that runs your role.

Comment: In fact, I see that after a reboot so as Sandrino Di Mattia said, the path may be different, and I earn a cutty exception ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you not create your file to file stream then upload the file? Please also consider the implications of running the worker role over multiple instances as reference to a file saved to C:\ might not exist depending upon the instance the role is on. LocalResource would be best suited for this example.

The startup task is typically used to execute batch files so you could potentially run a powershell script that uploads a text file using the [cerebrata cmdlets](http://cerebrata.com/Products/AzureManagementCmdlets/).

Comment: I can't create my file into a file stream because I use it with libraries (it is a sqlite file). I have not need to use your tool for my upload file because it is create in the Run() method, so after the startup task.